# How does SprintBoot support http2 h2c mode?

Tags: spring-boot, http2

I saw Spring Boot don't support HTTP2 h2c mode, but our project need use HTTP2 h2c server to receive the client requests.

Is there a way to support this capability on Spring Boot? or any other HTTP Server i can choose under java language?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot [supports h2c](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.webserver.configure-http2):

> You can enable HTTP/2 support in your Spring Boot application with the `server.http2.enabled` configuration property. Both `h2` (HTTP/2 over TLS) and `h2c` (HTTP/2 over TCP) are supported. To use `h2`, SSL must also be enabled. When SSL is not enabled, h2c will be used.